# Looping across columns for storing interpolated values

Tags: matlab, for-loop, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate values for all columns ranging from 2 to end column. . I wrote a code to put all the interpolated values for all the Nans in matrix.

eg: In column 1 corresponds to the independent variable, column 2 and 3 correspond to X and Y coordinates of an object '32'. Similary i wanted to loop over all column headers and put interpolated values. Any help to solve this will be appreciated.

```
data_to_be_interpolated = final_plot_matrix(:,2:end);
missing_part = zeros(length(data_to_be_interpolated,1),data_to_be_interpolated,2);
for ip = 1:1:data_to_be_interpolated
    missing_part(2:end,ip) = fillmissing(data_to_be_interpolated(2:end,ip),'linear','SamplePoints',data_to_be_interpolated(2:end,1));
end
missing_part(:,1) = data_to_be_interpolated(:,1);
missing_part(1,:) = data_to_be_interpolated(1,:);
```

Errors:

```
Error using matlab.internal.math.checkSamplePoints (line 27)
'SamplePoints' value contains Inf or NaN.

Error in fillmissing/parseInputs (line 424)
        x = matlab.internal.math.checkSamplePoints(varargin{i+1},A,false,dim,'fillmissing');

Error in fillmissing (line 116)
[A,AisTable,intM,intConstOrWinSize,extM,x,dim,dataVars] = 
parseInputs(A,fillMethod,varargin{:});

Error in intrepolation_data (line 15)

missing_part(2:end,ip) = fillmissing(data_to_be_interpolated(2:end,ip),'linear','SamplePoints',data_to_be_interpolated(2:end,1));
```

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Read (again) what a [mcve] is and why it is important for getting help

Comment: @AnderBiguri Apologies. I hope its clear now.

Comment: `zeros(length(data_to_be_interpolated,1),data_to_be_interpolated,2);` Does this work? `length` does not take two input arguments, and you seems to need a 2D matrix but `zeros` with 3 input arguments gives you a 3D matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. it will store the 'data_to_be_interpolated' values to the missingpart matrix from the second column.

```
   data_to_be_interpolated = final_plot_matrix(:,:);
   missing_part = 
   zeros(size(data_to_be_interpolated,1),size(data_to_be_interpolated,2)-1);

   for ip = 1:size(missing_part,2)
   missing_part(:,ip) = data_to_be_interpolated(:,ip+1);
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a for-loop to loop through each and every column.

```
missing_part = zeros(size(final_plot_matrix,1),size(final_plot_matrix,2));
for ip = 2:1:data_to_be_interpolated
    missing_part(2:end,ip) = fillmissing(final_plot_matrix(2:end,ip),'linear','SamplePoints',final_plot_matrix(2:end,1));
end
missing_part(:,1) = final_plot_matrix(:,1);
missing_part(1,:) = final_plot_matrix(1,:);
```

Remember, this `final_plot_matrix` should be the whole data.

Comment: @it doesnot seems to work. I added the modified code.

Comment: Take a look now. By the way are you really new in MATLAB?

Comment: yes. Just started learning recently. I am still getting an error. Modified code and error is shown.

Comment: Then you should try to debug the errors. Can you find whats wrong here? 

missing_part(2:end,ip) = fillmissing(data_to_be_interpolated(2:end,ip),'linear','SamplePoints',final_plot_matrix(2:end,1));

Look at this one and your's one inside for-loop. I hope you get it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried to debug it, I am still not able to solve it.

Comment: Just replace your code with this one. Hopefully this will work.

Comment: thanks. It works now without error, but it doesnot fill all the columns. Some columns just have 0's